# .NET Framework - features in 4.0 that's better than 3.0

Tags: .net-3.5, .net-4.0

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What features are people looking forward to in .Net 4.0 - 4.1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/710516/what-features-are-people-looking-forward-to-in-net-4-0-4-1)

Hi folks, i would like to know what is it that motivated you to move to .net 4.0 from earlier frameworks?

What specifically could be done better & what was the scenario?

TIA

Comment: Duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/710516/what-features-are-people-looking-forward-to-in-net-4-0-4-1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The task parallel library and the concurrent collections.

They both made many multi-threading situations much simpler.

Answer (score 1):

You can also take a look at [this similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1716146/most-interest-feature-of-visual-studio-2010-and-net-framework-4).  Although it's a mix of Visual Studio 2010 and .NET 4 features.

Answer (score 0):

Default parameters (more of a C# 4 feature than a CLR 4 feature though).